# How to show legend values as percent

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the following data:

```
   RW GA Freq   percFreq
    0  0    9 0.13043478
    0  3    1 0.01449275
    0 14    1 0.01449275
    0 16    1 0.01449275
    0 23    1 0.01449275
    0 25    1 0.01449275
    0 29    2 0.02898551
    0 30    1 0.01449275
    2 30    1 0.01449275
   15 30    2 0.02898551
   19 30    1 0.01449275
   22 30    1 0.01449275
   24 30    1 0.01449275
   29 30    1 0.01449275
   30 29   16 0.23188406
   30 30   29 0.42028986
```

I would like to change the legend values in the following plot to be shown as percent:

[image]

The script to generate the plot is:

```
ggplot(counts, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=as.factor(percFreq))) + geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
    scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30), breaks=lbreaks) +
    scale_color_discrete(name="Freq", breaks=lbreaks)
```

Basically, instead of showing 0.42028986 in the legend, I want it to be shown as 42%.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Use 'percent' from 'scales' library.

Load the `scales` library:

```
library(scales)
```

And add `labels = percent` to your discrete scale:

```
ggplot(counts, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=as.factor(percFreq))) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30), breaks=lbreaks) +
  scale_color_discrete(name="Freq", breaks=lbreaks, labels = percent(lbreaks, accuracy = .01))
```

If you want to change how it rounds the number, use the `accuracy` argument:

```
scales::percent(percFreq, accuracy = .001)
```

[image]

(this has `accuracy = .1`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error `Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Comment: Thanks. I run your cod but the legend disappeared. Do you have any idea what that is the case?

Comment: Can you provide the value of `lbreaks`? I think it has to do with that variable

Answer (score 2):

You can either transform `percFreq` into percentages

```
df$percFreq <- df$percFreq*100
```

or you can `color=as.factor(percFreq*100)))`

## ---- Reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(RW = round(runif(16,0,30)),
                 GA=round(runif(16,0,30)),
                 Freq=round(runif(16,1,30)),
                 percFreq = runif(16,0.1,0.9))
df$percFreq <- round(df$percFreq*100,digits = 2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=as.factor(percFreq))) +
       geom_point(alpha=0.7) + 
       scale_size(range = c(1, 10), name="Freq", limits=c(1,30)) +
       scale_color_discrete(name="%")
```

I would advise against, but if you want the `%` with the numbers, simply `paste(df$percFreq,"%",sep=" ")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Instead of showing 42.028986, how can I show it as 42.02%?

Comment: `round(df$percFreq,digits=2)`